# How do you call a function that returns a reference or throws an exception without gymnastics?

Tags: c++, exception, reference

Suppose you are presented with the following code:

```
blah & Foo::foo() { 
   if (_x) {  return _blah;}
   throw exception("blah error");
}
```

As far as I can tell, the only way to call this is in a try/catch block as so

```
try {
blah &b=_foo.foo();
catch(...) {}
```

Now b is out of scope, making error handling somewhat difficult.  One can assign it to a pointer, and then reassign the pointer to a reference below, but that seems rather difficult.

I don't recall an explicit suggestion to avoid creating functions that return references or throw exceptions, but is there a standard way to get around this issue when dealing with these kinds of interfaces?

Comment: You could always do whatever you were going to do after it in the try block and catch those possible exceptions in the same set of catches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the trick is to design your exceptions, exception handlers, and error handlers so that you do not run into situations like this. For example, you could enclose all operations that rely on `foo()`'s successful return in a `try` block, which allows you to handle exceptions thrown by *any* of those operations all in once place. Conceptually, you are "trying" to perform the entire task, rather than trying to perform individual steps independently, e.g.:

```
try { 
    blah &b = _foo.foo();
    b.dehydrate();
    _foo.reconceptualize(b);
    idealize(b, _foo, "grumble");
} catch (const exception &x) {
    // log/handle error
}
```

Another way to think about it is, if the validity of the reference `b` depends on the success of `foo()`, there is only really one place in your code where `b` is valid, and that's in the `try` block after `foo()` is called. Once you leave the `try` block, there could be no guarantee on the validity of `b` since at that point the exception may or may not have occurred.

```
try {
    blah &b = _foo.foo();
    // <- [1] this is the only point that we *know* foo() returned something valid
} catch (...) {
    // <- [2] here we *know* it didn't
}

// <- [3] here we don't know either way
```

Now if you had code that relied on `foo()`s success and `b`s validity, and you had to choose location 1, 2, or 3 above, which seems the most appropriate to you (hint: 1)?

Even if you used a pointer declared before the `try` block, it's fairly redundant to use e.g. `NULL` to indicate that an exception was thrown, when you already had that information available previously:

```
blah *b;

try {
    b = _foo.fooptr();
    // <- here we know an error did not occur
} catch (...) {
    // <- here we know an error occurred
    b = NULL; // <- so why do this...
}

// ... when we already had a perfectly good opportunity to handle above;
// we've kind of missed the boat at this point.
```

That's not to say there aren't cases where the pointer example isn't useful. Perhaps you don't care to do any special error handling or you are abstracting some API behind something else:

```
void * getData () {
    void *data = NULL;
    try {
        data = getFromThingThatMayThrow();
    } catch (...) {
        // we really don't care why it failed, and it's more convenient to
        // swallow it and return NULL instead.
    }
    return data;
}
```

But the take home point is, if you find your exception handling getting really weird and messy like in your example, you may be going down the wrong path, and you should consider stepping back and reassessing your error handling. Exceptions, when used appropriately, can *greatly* simplify error handling and recovery.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a misconception in your side. If the function above throws an exception, it does not complete and it does **not** yield a reference. The reference inside the `try/catch` block is not just inaccessible but it never even *existed*.

A function that throws an exception does **not** return.

Comment: +1 You very succinctly said one of the big points I tried to explain.

Answer (score 1):

As chris already mentioned in his comment, you do treat exceptions different from return codes in the sense that you don't wrap every function call that might throw in its own try/catch handler.

Instead of checking for exceptions like you would for return codes (after every function call) you push the exception handling up to the layer that's best equipped to handle the failure that's signaled by the exception. That one might well be several layers up from your current code.

As to returning references, there are a couple of guidelines like not returning references to local objects. In your case it looks like you might be returning a reference to a member, which is probably OK as long as you make sure that you don't run into object lifetime issues.

Comment: I guess that I object to the requirement for all callers to write exception-safe code for the remainder of the function -- if there was some way to pass a reference to an outer scope, I'd be happy.

Comment: @gbronner: You should *embrace* rather than *object* the writing of exception safe code. You should always assume that exceptions can happen *anywhere* in the code, if for no other reason because they might be injected sometime in the future. Also note that in most cases, correctly written exception safe code is as efficient as exception unsafe code.

Answer (score 1):

Something like a C++1y `optional` might help here.  I have seen a proposal for `expected<T,Otherwise>` as well.  You bundle the call into a pseudo-union with either the reference or error information.  You handle the error whenever you want, and otherwise access the data if you have checked for lack of error.

This leads to traditional in-line error handling, instead of exception-based 'come-from' error handling, which some prefer.